# Abnormal termination when calling `cvCreateCameraCapture(-1)`

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

My code as follow. When I execute `cvCreateCameraCapture(-1)` in `openCamera`, the app ends.

TIP: Abnormal program termination. during startup program exited with code 0X000135

Why?  The computer is notebook, and inner-Camera.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

>

```
#include<highgui.h>
#include<cv.h>

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT  
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private slots:
    void openCamera();
    void readFrame();
    void closeCamera();
    void takingPhote();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    QTimer* timer;
    QImage* image;
    CvCapture* cam;
    IplImage* frame;
};

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    cam = NULL;
    timer = new QTimer(this);
    image = new QImage;

    connect(ui->openCamera, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(openCamera()));
}

void MainWindow::openCamera()
{
   cam = cvCreateCameraCapture(-1);
   // timer->start(33);
   // connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(readFrame()));
}
```

Comment: What Operating system? I recommend experimenting with `0` instead of `1`, and after that call is executed, check it's return: `if (!cam) qDebug() << "!!! cam failed";`

Comment: The OS is win7、when i press the run button, TIP: 1:RUN  2: abnormal terminaation 3: end.  i.e. the app doesn't work. if i didn't use the opencv function, the it can run normally.  what is the problem, or I need to set the envirnment-Variable for run the opencv? Thank you..

Comment: I want you to replace the `cvCreateCameraCapture()` call for something else, like `cvWaitKey(0);`. If this is a runtime issue related to environment variables and Windows not finding OpenCV, this simple test will show. If it continues to crash, then it might really be related to the environment configuration.

Comment: yeah, the environment configuration is the point..I hava solved it. Thank you helping me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding my previous comment as an answer since it helped you solve the problem:

> I want you to replace the `cvCreateCameraCapture()` call for something else, like `cvWaitKey(0);`. If this is a runtime issue related to environment variables and Windows not finding OpenCV, this simple test will show. So, if it continues to crash then it might really be related to the environment configuration.